ESNIC registry xml login request
I am scratching my head to create a basic schema for login for ESNIC registry.
This is my xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
    <command>
        <login>
            <clID>$login</clID>
            <pw>$password</pw>
            <options>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <lang>en</lang>
            </options>
            <svcs>
                <objURI>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0</objURI>
                <objURI>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:contact-1.0</objURI>
                <objURI>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:host-1.0</objURI>
                <svcExtension>
                    <extURI>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:secDNS-1.1</extURI>
                </svcExtension>
            </svcs>
        </login>
        <extension></extension>
        <clTRID>cid-login-request-etewr31</clTRID>
    </command>
</epp>

But I only see this in response
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
<response>
<result code="2001">
<msg lang="es">
<![CDATA[
Error,XML incorrecto:  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 26; cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: El contenido del elemento 'extension' no está completo. Se esperaba uno de '{WC[##other:"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0"]}'.]]>
</msg>
</result>
<trID>
<clTRID>000</clTRID>
<svTRID>1730656826070</svTRID>
</trID>
</response>
</epp>

I am unable to find any doc that would suggest me what needs to go inside the extension block at all

Check the schema "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" for types and required parameters.
